# Why doesn't the UpSampling2d Keras layer work?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, convolution, autoencoder

I tried to build a convolutional autoencoder in keras but it doesn't seem to work properly.
First of all, here's the Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import h5py
import random
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from os import getcwd

learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 10000
batch_size = 200
data_len = 400
training_data = []

for filename in tqdm(glob('D:/AI/Celeba/*.jpg')[0:data_len],desc='loading images'):
    im = scipy.misc.imread(filename)
    im = scipy.misc.imresize(im,(128,128))
    training_data.append(im)
training_data = np.array(training_data)
example = random.choice(training_data)

autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32,5,activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(4,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(2,3,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D())
autoencoder.add(Flatten())
autoencoder.add(Dense(32,activation='sigmoid'))
autoencoder.add(Dense(32,activation='sigmoid'))
autoencoder.add(Reshape((4,4,2)))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(2,3,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(4,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D())
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(3,5,activation='relu'))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=learning_rate),loss=categorical_crossentropy)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    autoencoder.fit(x=training_data,y=training_data,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1)
    output = autoencoder.predict(np.array([example]))[0]
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('training step: {}'.format(epoch+1))
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(example)
    a.set_title('Original')
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(output)
    imgplot.set_clim(0.0,0.7)
    a.set_title('Reconstruction')
    plt.savefig(getcwd()+'/training/{}.png'.format(epoch))

    if (epoch+1)%10 == 0:
        autoencoder.save(getcwd()+'/saved/model.h5')
```

So my Problem is that the model is outputting the wrong shape. The Output shape is `[batch_size, 2, 2, 3]` when it should be `[batch_size, 128, 128, 3]`.
I have done some debugging and found out some possible reasons for why the model is outputting the wrong dimensions:

1. The `UpSampling2D` layer isn't doing anything
2. The last `Conv2D` layer is reducing the size of the Image by 2 for some reason

Does anybody know how I could fix this?

PS.
While writing this I realized that my debugging results could be interpreted in another way:

1. The `UpSampling2D` layer is working fine
2. All of the `Conv2D` layers are reducing the size of the Image by 2 so the Image always stays 2*2 tall

Comment: You should include the output of model.summary(), it will tell you the exact shapes of the output of each layers.

Answer (score 1):

In the Conv2D layer you are reducing the size of the input.

In a convolution if you take a 32 by 32 images and you apply a kernel of 5x5.  The output image will be of size 28 by 28.

A Kernel of 3 by 3 would result in 30 by 30 image, and 4 by 4 would give you a 29 by 29 image.

If you want to prevent the convolution from reducing in size, you could add padding to it.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246512/convolutional-layers-to-pad-or-not-to-pad) Provides a good resource for knowing whether to pad.

Also it's good to know whether downsampling will round down or up when the size is an odd number, this might help you later on.  I believe it is round down.

I also strongly recommend you do autoencoder.summary()  this will give you information about the dimensions at each layer.  With this you can figure out what is happening at each layer.

Comment: I set `padding` to `'same'` and that worked perfectly! Thank you!